# sqlite3_exec() Callback function clarification

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

I am having trouble understanding the use of the callback function in a SQLite3 database.

I understand it is used to traverse SELECT statements with multiple records. But I do not understand how it does that or how to make my own *useful* callback. I have read through [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) several times to try to understand, but that is just not doing it for me.

When I use their example and debug in Visual Studio to see how the argument arrays are populated and traversed i get lost. Also VS only shows the current slot in the array, not the entire array itself.

If you need any clarification please let me know as I am here to learn!

I am asking for someone to explain how the callback is used. Maybe some examples of how others have used it. Just an explanation of what this one is doing even:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?  This is a Q/A website.

Comment: For general q/a about the topic, you should probably ask on one of the mailing lists (see http://www.sqlite.org/support.html). Stack Overflow requires you to have a much more specific question (typically involving code you've written and cannot make work).

Comment: I think if you were to explain what you mean by "useful callback" it might help someone answer. What do you want your callback to do? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too broad".  Although no question has been asked, I'm assuming the implied question is *"What would it take to make me better understand this topic?"* or something similar.

Comment: I don't understand why people so often want to close a post like this :-( For me and the person who gave the accepted answer and, at the moment, at least 36 upvoters the implied question seems obvious. The accepted answer is probably one of the best resources on the Internet which I am very thankful for. Would you have closed the question, we wouldn't have this!!!

Comment: 6 years later and SQL Lite documentation still "confusing", this answer stay interresting and need more "+".

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Let's assume you have a very simple table called `User` that looks something like this:

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ Name     ║
╟────╫──────────╢
║ 1  ║ Slvrfn   ║
║ 2  ║ Sean     ║
║ 3  ║ Drew     ║
║ 4  ║ mah      ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

And you call `sqlite3_exec` like this (the arguments are described in detail [in the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)):

```
/* Error handling omitted for brevity */
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM User", my_special_callback, NULL, NULL);
```

SQLite will execute the passed SQL statement and for every result row that it finds it will call `my_special_callback`. So with our example `User` table, `my_special_callback` will be called 4 times. So let's create `my_special_callback`:

```
/*
 * Arguments:
 *
 *   unused - Ignored in this case, see the documentation for sqlite3_exec
 *    count - The number of columns in the result set
 *     data - The row's data
 *  columns - The column names
 */
static int my_special_callback(void *unused, int count, char **data, char **columns)
{
    int idx;

    printf("There are %d column(s)\n", count);

    for (idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
        printf("The data in column \"%s\" is: %s\n", columns[idx], data[idx]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Given our example table and data, the output will look like this:

```
There are 2 column(s)
The data in column "ID" is: 1
The data in column "Name" is: Slvrfn

There are 2 column(s)
The data in column "ID" is: 2
The data in column "Name" is: Sean

There are 2 column(s)
The data in column "ID" is: 3
The data in column "Name" is: Drew

There are 2 column(s)
The data in column "ID" is: 4
The data in column "Name" is: mah
```

Now to how to make this useful, that is where the 4th argument to `sqlite3_exec` comes in. From the documentation:

> The 4th argument to sqlite3_exec() is relayed through to the 1st
>   argument of each callback invocation.

So let's say that we want to run our SQL and build a linked list of the names of all of our users. The first thing we need to do is change how we are calling `sqlite3_exec`:

```
/* Create my fictional linked list */
struct my_linked_list *head = my_linked_list_alloc();

/*
 * Pass a pointer to my list as the 4th argument to sqlite3_exec. Error
 * handling omitted for brevity
 */
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM User", my_special_callback, head, NULL);

/* My list is now built, I can do stuff with it... */
my_linked_list_traverse(head, /* ... Stuff ... */);
```

And modify `my_special_callback` to use it

```
/*
 * Arguments:
 *
 *     list - Pointer to a linked list of names
 *    count - The number of columns in the result set
 *     data - The row's data
 *  columns - The column names
 */
static int my_special_callback(void *list, int count, char **data, char **columns)
{
    struct my_linked_list *head = list;

    /*
     * We know that the value from the Name column is in the second slot
     * of the data array.
     */
    my_linked_list_append(head, data[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you were to use the `callback` you included in your question, you would call it like this:

```
/*
 * Pass the table name as the 4th argument to sqlite3_exec. Error
 * handling omitted for brevity
 */
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM User", callback, "User", NULL);
```

The output would be:

```
User: 
ID = 1
Name = Slvrfn

User: 
ID = 2
Name = Sean

... etc ...
```

(Except the `User:` part would be printed to stderr instead of stdout)

Hopefully this helps clear things up for you. Let me know if there is still something that you don't understand.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the help!
One last question though, in your explanation of the callback argument, is count the number of _columns_ or _rows_?

Comment: It's the column count

Comment: but if i call sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM User", callback, "User", NULL); and go into debug, the callback count argument would be 4. Isnt that 4 records, so 4 rows?

Comment: The callback function (called `callback` in your question and `my_special_callback` earlier in my answer) has the following signature: `int cbfunc(void *user_supplied_data, int column_count, char **row_data, char **columns)` - Which of those arguments are you talking about being "4?" With my example table and example SQL statement, the `column_count` value in the callback will be 2.

Comment: I misinterpreted. Going through your code and mine I believe I see what you are saying, please correct me if I am wrong. I previously thought that the callback contained **every** returned statement from the SELECT statement. Instead the callback is only looking at **one** returned statement from the SELECT statement each time it is called, so the count refers to the column count of the SELECTed statement.

Comment: The callback function is called 1 time for each of the rows that the SQL statement returns. So if running `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM SomeTable` returned 100 rows of data, the callback function will be called 100 times. Each time the callback function is called, the second argument that is passed to it will be "2" indicating the number of columns in that row (`Column1` and `Column2`). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes! I believe I have reached the answer i was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: I think in the first callback function example. It should be *There are 2 column(s)* instead of *There are 4 column(s)*

Comment: @SeanBright It seems that callback function called `my_special_callback ` only invoked when `select` operation, but not when `insert` or `delete` operation.

Comment: @kgbook those statements don’t generate a result set, so that makes sense.

Comment: What if my data is numbers, i.e. REAL? It doesn't look like I can use e.g. sqlite3_column_double in a callback function, so what is the correct thing to do?

Comment: @BenFarmer, "[The `sqlite3_exec()` interface is a convenience wrapper around `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_step()`, and `sqlite3_finalize()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)" - So if you want to get the column values as something other than a string you need to use the 3 other functions.

Comment: What is the callback return int used for?

Comment: @Marvin it's described in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). In short, if non-zero it makes `sqlite3_exec()` return `SQLITE_ABORT` and prevents the callback from being called again.

Comment: I don't like the fact that it is a static int. I tried to make it non static because I wanted to use the function in a class, but it complained. I hate static functions

Comment: This example uses a static function, but you can pass any function pointer to `sqlite3_exec()`.

Comment: @SeanBright The information about the **return value** of the callback (as already given in your comment) is important. It's really hard to find in the original documentation due to lack of text structure (and maybe typography): The only way is to conscientiously read through the entire text from the beginning, which most (modern) readers try to avoid given the other obviousness of the declaration. Hopefully you will eventually find the time to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 46):

That tutorial is horrible, because it does not use anything but `sqlite3_exec()`.

In the general case, the *only* useful way to use `sqlite3_exec()` is to replace it with [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)/[sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)/[sqlite3_column_*()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)/[sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) calls so that you can read the data in the same place where you actually need to handle it:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM User";
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    print("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return;
}
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    int id           = sqlite3_column_int (stmt, 0);
    const char *name = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
    // ...
}
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    print("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post your unapproved answer [on my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35141039/105539), not here, because it doesn't answer the author's question but does answer my question? BTW, I used a variation of your code above in my project and it did solve my problem perfectly.

Comment: Such a beautiful solution. Thank you cl

Comment: Very good option. In fact what is missing in the callback way of using is knowing how many times the callback will be called. If you have (eg) to send the data from many results between a "start" and a "end" code, using the callback became complicated while using CL. solution is pretty easier.

Comment: That's exactly the part that is missing in the original documentation of [sqlite3_exec](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html).