# How To Get SQLite Records in Single Class Method in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, lambda

In this example...

http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

...I see how to use `sqlite3_exec()` with a callback class method or function in order to get a recordset and iterate through it.

Well, what if I want to create a class `DB` and have a static class method

`static void * getRS(void *hDB,std::string sSQL)`  ?

I'm kind of new with C++ but getting the hang of it extremely rapidly. Is there a way in C++ to create like a Lambda function, get the results from that, and pass them back? Or, is there another technique to return a std::map, std::multimap, etc. that I can iterate through each row?

(Note, I'm using XCode and calling C++ from a db.static.mm file in my Objective C project, if that matters.)

This question is not a duplicate of [sqlite3_exec() Callback function Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31146713/105539). In that question, the author asks essentially *how the callback is used* in `sqlite3_exec()`. In my question, I'm asking how to do a top-down approach of SQLite3 code *instead of using a callback*. It just so happens that someone left an answer (not the approved answer, mind you) that solves *my problem*, not that author's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution to do this in a top-down (rather than callback) manner is to not use [sqlite3_exec()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). Instead, do it with [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), and then [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html). Optionally, one can inject/bind query parameters with various [sqlite3_bind_*()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) calls.

[Here's an example of the proper code for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31168999/105539)