# Get count of rows in sqlite table using c in a program

Tags: sqlite

How to get count of rows in sqlite table using c in a program? Is it only by running "select * from table" ? and incrementing a variable?

1. 

```
sqlQuery = "select count (*) from company;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
printf("prepare status for count : %d\n", rc);
rowcount = sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

2. 

```
sqlQuery = "select * from company;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
printf("prepare status for count : %d\n", rc);
while (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(stmt)) {
   rowcount ++; 
}
```

I am not getting the row count with 1,

But I do get it when I perform 2.

Answer (score 5):

The `sqlite3_step()` function does not return the results of the query. It returns `SQLITE_ROW` if there is another row in the result set, or `SQLITE_DONE` if there isn't. It also returns an error code if something bad happened.

```
sqlQuery = "select count(*) from company;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
  // error handling -> statement not prepared
}
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (rc != SQLITE_ROW) {
  // error handling -> no rows returned, or an error occurred
}
rowcount = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
```

To get the values for the current row in the result set, you have to access them by column index, using the prepared statement that is executing the query. Since there is only one column in this query, the index of `0` is used for the left-most, or only, column in the result. And, since the value of that column is an integer, we use the `sqlite3_column_int()` function, which returns the value as a 32-bit integer.

For most ordinary database operations, you only need to use a few of the functions in the SQLite C API. You should really read and absorb the [introduction](http://sqlite.org/cintro.html). It will help you to understand the normal workflow for database operations.

Comment: In my opinion, it is very difficult to get from *the [introduction](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html)* to this point. I still hesitate to upvote this answer as long as it omits `sqlite3_finalize(stmt);` …

Comment: To *copy-paste coders*: see also the example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31168999/2932052