# C++ from SQL to XML?

Tags: c++, xml, sqlite

I'm still writing on the same c++ program, my SQL database stuff works so far, now I just need to pull the data from my SQL and convert it to XML, so I can display it on a website. But so far all my attempts fail. I have found a few posts that suggest solutions in C#, but since I'm programming in C++ those posts won't help me.

Here is my function to pull the data from sql (which works) except the part with XML

```
void tbl_to_xml(string target_tbl)
{
sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg = 0;

int rc = sqlite3_open("db_test", &db);


if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
}



std::string sql = std::string("SELECT * FROM dbo.Department FOR XML PATH('Department'), ROOT ('Structure')");

//

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), 0, 0, &err_msg);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

    sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Thanks for any hints that help solve this mystery!

Answer (score 1):

Look like you missed to mention callback function in sqlline_exec.

Your callback function need to traverse the resultset and produce the xml file.

refer details of callback use in below response. [sqlite3_exec() Callback function Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146713/sqlite3-exec-callback-function-clarification)