# Fetching data with sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

I have been trying to use the SQLite tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) to learn how to use SQLite in C. I was having trouble figuring out exactly how to use it, as it only mentions the `sqlite3_exec`, which seems incredibly un-intuitive to use for basic querying (it uses a callback for everything). Then I came across this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31168999/11954200, which addresses this same issue and suggests using the various four sqlite statements that are essentially merged into the `sqlite3_exec` shorthand form. Here is my understanding so far:

```
// Query to get the rows

// Part1 -- Prepare the query: cursor.execute()
// http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html
sqlite3_stmt *stmt; // this is the prepared statement that the sqlite3_prepare writes to
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20", -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 0;
}


// Part2 -- equivalent of cursor.fetchone()
// http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html
int rownum=1;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {

    // Part3 -- reference the values from the row
    // http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html
    int id                       = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    const unsigned char * date   = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
    printf("Row: %d | ID: %d | Date: %s\n", rownum, id, date);
    rownum++;
}

// Part4 -- equivalent of cursor.close()
// http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

In other words, in higher language parlance:

- `sqlite3_prepare(...)` works like `cursor.execute(...)`
- `sqlite3_step(...)` works like `cursor.fetchone(...)`
- `sqlite3_finalize(...)` works like `cursor.close(...)`;

Is this an accurate assessment of how these statements work in sqlite? Would the `sqlite3_exec` ever be used when fetching results?

Comment: Any tutorial suggesting that you use that callback to `sqlite3_exec()` instead of prepared statements is bad and should be ignored.

Comment: @Shawn why do you say that, out of curiosity?

Comment: It causes unnecessary data conversion because everything is turned into a string - if you're storing integers or reals, that's silly, and if you're using blobs, it's really bad. It's a pain to get the resulting rows back to the caller to process there. It can make code harder to read by having to jump to another function to see what you do with the results, and most importantly, it means you can't bind values to parameters in a query, opening yourself up to sql injection, errors from badly quoted strings, etc.

Comment: `sqlite3_exec()` is best for DDL statements that don't return any values or depend on user-supplied data - creating tables, etc.

Comment: @Shawn do you want to go ahead and put in an answer with your above two comments and I'll accept it?