# I don not indentify this problem on codeblock ide. when run this code

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I write a code of a simple console application. when compile it is compiled successfully but when it run into the code block id it give some error. i will share the code and the error images and the compiler setting pictures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include <chrono>
#include "restclient-cpp/restclient.h"
#include "restclient-cpp/connection.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;

static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    string str, str1, file_name;
            unsigned __int64 ms = chrono::duration_cast< chrono::milliseconds >(chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            str = to_string(ms);
            str1 = ".xml";
            file_name = str.append(str1);
            cout << "File name is - " << file_name << endl;
            int filename_len = file_name.length();
            char filename[filename_len];
            strcpy(filename, file_name.c_str());
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s = %s \n", azColName[i], argv[i]);
            //Sleep(30);
            XMLDocument xmlDoc;
            XMLNode * pRoot = xmlDoc.NewElement("Root");
            xmlDoc.InsertFirstChild(pRoot);
            for(int j=0; j<argc; j++){
                XMLElement * pElement = xmlDoc.NewElement(azColName[j]);
                pElement->SetText(argv[j]);
                pRoot->InsertEndChild(pElement);
                xmlDoc.SaveFile(filename);
                //File Data Parse
            }
            string str, temp, str2;
            ifstream fin;
            fin.open(filename);
            if(!fin){
                cout << " File is not open" << endl;
            }else{
                cout << " File is open success" << endl;
            while(fin){
                getline(fin, temp);
                //cout << temp << endl;
                str = temp;
                str2= str2+str;
        }
        cout <<" File xml Data to send api = " << str2 << endl;
        fin.close();
        }

        RestClient::Response ob = RestClient::get("www.google.com");
        if(ob.code == 200){
            cout << "Connection Establish" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Retry more time" << endl;
        }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i Will also upload the picture of the error code
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc1gy.png)[linker_setting[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP1cY.png)
but my code does not any error. why it is give it

```
int main()
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    char* messagesError;
    int exit = sqlite3_open("newinformation.db", &DB);
    if (exit) {
        cerr << "Error open DB " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << endl;
        return (-1);
    }
    else
        cout << "Opened Database Successfully!" << endl;
    string query = "SELECT id,amount,businessdate,checknumber,localdata,localtime,requestcode,revenuecenter,terminalid,track2,TransactionEmployee,security,refid FROM SOCKETDATA ;";
    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, query.c_str(), callback, NULL, &messagesError);
    sqlite3_close(DB);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Possibly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146713/sqlite3-exec-callback-function-clarification/31168999

Comment: Also, what is the output of your program? What happens? Or to be more precise: what _doesnt_ happen? Have you checked if your query is executed properly? Is the question about getting the data from "callback" back into your main?

Comment: You'd likely be happier with `sqlite3_prepare`, `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_value_text` et al. Much easier to extract individual values than digging them out of the whole table's worth of data in the callback.

Comment: The error is because you have linked against `libcurl.dll` but the the windows loader can't find it at launch as it's not in the search path.